# How to change old permalink?

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, links

My old permalink structure is `/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`. 
For example:

`https://example.com/index.php/2019/01/08/technological-innovation-for-agriculture-sector-in-india/`

but I want to change to "Post name". For example:

```
https://example.com/sample-post/
```

also, want to remove `index.php`.

When I change the permalink my old post or pages are not working

Answer (score 0):

Well you have several options, but you definitely need to redirect the url.

You can either achieve the redirection via a Wordpress plugin or through your .htaccess file.

If you would like to use a plugin, I would recommend "Redirection" by John Godley.

It is easy to use. Just type the url you want to redirect from & to.

Comment: If I would like to change using htaccess so do i have to change permalink setting ?

Comment: @TarunSharma No, leave the new permalink structure. Take a look at the plugin suggested by Niklas, by default it uses WordPress itself for redirections but it can export to .htaccess too: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 0):

The old links have stopped working because they no longer exist.

1) If the site is live you should change the permalink structure back to the way it was because you run the risk of having the pages removed from the Google index.

2) Before changing the permalink structure it's important to set up a redirect to the new location.

[Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) is a great plugin to help you with this.